# Get the value of the earliest and the latest date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, mindate

I have a table that shows the delivery day that customers choose, but this can change and the table adds a new record per change, so I want a table that gets the first value they choose and the last one they choose.

The table is something like this:

| user_id | Day | DateUpdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Friday | 2021/07/01 |
| 3 | Sunday | 2021/07/01 |
| 3 | Tuesday | 2021/07/15 |
| 4 | Monday | 2021/07/02 |
| 4 | Wednesday | 2021/07/18 |
| 5 | Thursday | 2021/07/12 |
| 7 | Monday | 2021/07/01 |
| 7 | Wednesday | 2021/07/16 |

And the result I want should be this:

| User_id | first_day | last_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Friday | Friday |
| 3 | Sunday | Tuesday |
| 4 | Monday | Wednesday |
| 5 | Thursday | Thursday |
| 7 | Monday | Wednesday |

What function should I Use? Could you help me please? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want the date or day in the result table?

Comment: Please confirm that your `DateUpdate` column date format is exactly as your example (`YYYY/MM/DD`) or is it actually the standard `DATE` datatype format of `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is important because you can't directly use [date manipulation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) if it's not standard [date datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the day name can actually be found using the `DAYNAME()` function, so there is actually no need to store it in another column. But anyways, try this code.

```
SELECT 
user_id,
DAYNAME(MIN(DateUpdate)) as first_day,
DAYNAME(MAX(DateUpdate)) as last_day
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user_id
```

You could also remove the `DAYNAME()` function if you just want the dates.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT INTO TABLE**

> MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (user_id,first_day,last_day)
SELECT tbl_temp1.user_id,tbl_temp1.first_day,tbl_temp1.last_day
FROM tbl_temp1 
WHERE <Need to add your selection criteria here>;
```

[Reference doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)